# How to reinstall Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have installed **Elasticsearch**.
**How can I reinstall** it so that I get a **new and clean elastic, a new password, fingerprint and token for kibana**?
I'm asking because I use the same bat file for installing and starting. I tried deleting the file under Appdata, but it makes no difference.

Comment: How did you install Elasticsearch? If it's installed as a service, try uninstalling it and delete all the files/ folders specified in the configuration.
If its extracted form ZIP, check on the ES config and jvm.options where the files reside and remove those directories.
If SSL was enabled, worth checking in JKS keystore of your machine if it has any certificate stored for your ES and delete that entry.